how to restart golang server using go realize in Windows
I install realize using go get github.com/oxequa/realize/realize this and run ~/go/bin/realize start this command to setup the realizer in golang project. but this give error saying '~' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.. how can i solve this error??

Either add $HOME/go/bin to your PATH, or use a shell that interprets ~ as $HOME or use an absolute path or use $HOME/go/bin/realize. All this has literally nothing to do with Go or realize but your shell only.

C:\Users\YourUsername\go\bin\realize start I try this to for that and still give 'realize' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. this error

This is a plain Windows problem. Make sure realize is executable, matches your platform and OS, etc, pp.

You need to build the code first.
